# Seeking 3D point and vector geometry C++ library for simulating particle trajectories

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, geometry

I am looking for a point and vector class for simulating particle trajectories in a Cartesian 3D coordinate system. Functionality needed: compute distances between a point and X, compute intersections between a ray and X, rotate and translate X (where X is a plane or a sphere).

I looked at boost:geometry (too generic, too complicated), at blitz::TinyVector (good base, but lacking geometric functionality), at Qt::QVector3D (perhaps the best starting point).

Comment: izomorphius gave a good suggestion, but might I suggest implementing it on your own? Or do you have deadlines to compete against? It's really a fun experience and gets you exactly what you want. The feeling of satisfaction on its own is almost worth the effort. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a look at [cgal](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/contents.html) It is an extremely powerful geometric library, but also has what you need.